# JS XRegExp Replace all non characters

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, replace, xregexp

My objective is to replace all characters which are not dash (-) or not number or not letters in any language in a string.All of the #!()[], and all other signs to be replaced with empty string. All occurences of - should not be replaced also.
I have used for this the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) plugin but it seems I cannot find the magic solution :)
I have tryed like this :

```
var txt = "Ad СТИНГ (ALI) - Englishmen In New York";
var regex = new XRegExp('\\p{^N}\\p{^L}',"g");
var b = XRegExp.replace(txt, regex, "")
```

but the result is : AСТИН(AL EnglishmeINeYork ... which is kind of weird

If I try to add also the condition for not removing the '-' character leads to make the RegEx invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\p{^N}\\p{^L}` means a non-number followed by a non-letter.

Try `[^\\p{N}\\p{L}-]` that means a non-number, non-letter, non-dash.

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syu69/2/) where to do some tests... The third `XRegExp` is the one you asked.

Comment: `[\p{^N}\p{^L}]` matches anything that isn't a number *or* isn't a letter—which unless there's a character that is both a letter *and* a number is everything!

Comment: @bobince `Note that the union of non-number and non-letters is probably the whole Unicode`

Comment: I see in your example that Test 1 is leaving all letters intact and is replacing the spaces and numbers. Why is that when you add {N} all letters are replaced also? All I wanna do is replace the characters which are not dash, not numbers or not letters from any language.

Answer (score 1):

```
\p{^N}\p{^L}
```

is a non-number followed by a non-letter. You probably meant to say a character that is neither a letter nor a number:

```
[^\p{N}\p{L}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// all non letters/numbers in a string => /[^a-zA-z0-9]/g
```

I dont know XRegExp.

but in js Regexp you can replace it by

```
b.replace(/[^a-zA-z0-9]/g,'')
```